# SQL Delete a single row by PK is very slow

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, sql-delete, sql-execution-plan, sqlperformance

In our app, we can undo the creation of a Task just created.
As an example we would issue the following delete:

```
delete from task where taskid = 290313
```

This is very slow and can take up to 30 seconds to execute.

Dozens of tables have a foreign key to Task, and TaskId is indexed in all of them.

Looking at the Execution Plan, I can see many Index Scan (non Seek) that reads all records in the index.
[image]

Why is it using a full Index Scan instead of Seek ?

I'm on Azure SQL Database latest version.

[EDIT]

Indexes on Task table:

[image]

Query plan here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJtzfNyp7

Here is the result of a Live Query Statistics, we clearly see the time lost to Index Scan:
[image]

Comment: Can you list the indexes for that table? It's using a NC Scan not your Clustered Seek which is what you would have by default on the PK. But, the PK doesn't have to be the clustered index

Comment: You mean the Task table or the TaskTransitionLog table shown in the image ? I could provide the full execution plan xml, but i don't know how to attach it here...

Comment: You can post it [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and then provide the link. But also can you provide the `create index` statements for that table?

Comment: For which table ? :-)

Comment: The one you are deleting from: `task `

Comment: Wow nice site !  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJtzfNyp7

Comment: You realise that you're not just deleting from one table?  You have multiple tables referencing it with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.  So, when you delete a `Task` record, you're also deleting it's associated records in `TaskAttachment` and `TaskComment` and `TaskCommentRecipient`, etc, etc, plus all of those tables associated indexes.  For example; the cascaded delete on `TaskUserNotification` is deleting via a non clustered index, and that Index Seek is responsible for 15% of the overall cost and another 12% for the associated table spool to find and amend the underling record (27% total)...

Comment: Yes, but there is no child records existing at all, it is a newly created Task. How come it cannot use the NC Index on TaskId defined in all tables having FK to Task ?

Comment: It ***is*** using the Non Clustered index.  The way a non clustered index works is almost like having a second table, with it's own clustered index.  You can quickly find the record(s) in the non clustered index, to find the row identifier(s) in the clustered index, then join that on to the underlying table to find that actual row(s).  The Execution plan has to be build on the presumption that it MIGHT find records in that table.  Until it has executed it doesn't KNOW whether there are any records to delete or not.  In the case of `TaskUserNotification`, that takes a while.

Comment: It is using the NC Index, but with a Full Scan, not a Seek on TaskId. This is what I don't understand.

Comment: In the Plan you pasted in the link, the third from bottom track is for `TaskUserNotification`, that's using an Index Seek, not a Scan.  I have to go now, but I suggest reading some tutorials on understanding execution plans and paying careful attention to detail in this case.  In the cases that Are using scans, the cost is showing at 0%, in other words you're worrying about the places that are fast and not paying attention to the actual details in the places that are slow.

Comment: Well Index Scan show millions rows being read, depicted by a huge arrow, i thought this mattered...anyway i will try disabling all the cascade deletes and see if it helps. Thanks !

Comment: If it says `cost : 0%` and another says `cost : 15%` you might want to consider that 15% is quite a bit higher than 0%.  That's why reading tutorials on execution plan is going to be worth while.  This forum is not the place to disect the ***entire*** query plan for you.

Comment: Just asking why Full Index Scans are being used instead of Seek, which haven't been answered.

Comment: Added a Live Query Statistics extract showing time lost on Index Scans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dropped and re-created all Foreign Keys with NO cascade delete.
Now the execution plan is using efficient Index Seeks to check RI on all FKs.

Not sure why having cascade delete enabled caused these Index Scans though...